# Laravel: Redirect the user to a custom 404 page when the given params are invalid

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I made an application where a user can create some papers and see all data in a template. Every paper has a **joincode** which is generated at its creation.

I defined the join route in my **web.php** like this:

```
Route::get('/conceptPaper/lobby/{joincode}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ConceptPaperController@join');
```

and the join function in the controller the following way:

```
public function join($joincode)
    {
        try { 
            $conceptPaper = ConceptPaper::where('join_code', $joincode)->firstOrFail();
            return response()->json($conceptPaper);
        } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return view('errors.404');
        }
    }
```

I used **firstOrFail** to check if the join code exists. If it exists it should return a response, otherwise it should redirect the user to a custom 404 page.

I created a custom component which gets the join code as a route param and shows the concept paper

```
{
        path: '/conceptPaper/lobby/:joincode',
        name: 'conceptPaper',
        component: () => import('./views/ConceptPaper.vue')
    },
```

So when the user joins a lobby with the right code he gets redirected to the page with all data from the corresponding paper:

```
showPaper: async function (conceptPaper) {
      const joinCode = conceptPaper.join_code;
      this.$router.push({ name: "conceptPaper", params: { joincode: joinCode }, });
    },
```

My problem is that when the user types in the wrong code he still gets redirected to the view. When I check the response in the network tab its shows the 404 page.

I think I built it fundamentally wrong. Can anyone tell me how to do it the right way? When the suer types in the correct join code he should see the **ConceptPaper.vue** view. When the code is wrong he should be redirected to the 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code I'm assuming that you're using VueJs as an SPA and you're retrieving the data from your laravel backend API.

Based on that, your join function is supposed to return json data that you use in your frontend, but in case the `ConceptPaper` was not found, you return a view instead of json, which won't change much because you're just changing the data that your front-end receives, but the front-end component is not changed.

What I'd do is remove the try catch block, which will return a 404 response from the API, and handle the 404 case in vue, and create a `NotFound` view in vue.

Laravel

```
public function join($joincode)
{
    $conceptPaper = ConceptPaper::where('join_code', $joincode)->firstOrFail();
    return response()->json($conceptPaper);
}
```

Vue

`router/index.js`

```
const routes = [
  // previous routes
  {
    path: '/not-found',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: () => import('../views/NotFound.vue')
  }
]
```

`NotFound.vue`

```
<template>
// page here
</template>
export {
    name: 'NotFound'
}
```

And finally handle the not found API call, if you are using axios

```
axios.get('/conceptPaper/lobby/-1000')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
        this.$router.push('NotFound');
    }
  });
```